# Create elasticsearch geo_point using Serilog

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, serilog

I'm using Serilog to push log messages to elasticsearch, so I can visualize the log data in Kibana.

Now, I'd like to push some geo_points to elastic. But how? Is it even possible?

I've tried this:

```
Log.ForContext<MyClass>().ForContext("GeoPoint",     
geoPoint.text).Information(geoPointJSON);
```

with geoPointJSON containing a geo-point as object like this:

```
{
    "text":"Test location",
    "location":
    {
        "lat":"47,391624",
        "lon":"12,635912"
     }
}
```

(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html)

But then in Kibana I get this:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.11.11",
  "_type": "logevent",
  "_id": "AVhVJug8Um5uh8sCEYD7",
  .
  .
  .
    "message": "{\"text\":\"Test location\",\"location\":  
        {\"lat\":\"47,234325\",\"lon\":\"11,880672\"}}",
        "fields": {
        "GeoPoint": "Test location",
        "SourceContext": "myClass"
    }
}
```

which doesn't seem right.

Can I push geo-points to elasticsearch using serilog in order to visualize the geopoints with Kibanas Tile map? And how?